# Cyrillic tag is not displayed as tag in revisions

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app, localization

The [post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/176217) contains tags in the body: first one with Latin symbols and second one with Cyrillic. Post's body looks good:

> [image: body]

But when I'm watching revisions - only one (Latin) tag showed as tag:

- inline:

  > [image: inline]
- side-by-side:

  > [image: side-by-side]

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)