# Stolen bounty day

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, bounties, ios-app

My [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286784/339911) has an open bounty. iOS app says:

> [image: app]

Web says:

> [image: web]

iOS app, please, bring back a stolen day!

I think it's related to another [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288576/339911).

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.3.

The web was rounding future dates to the nearest day with `(int)Math.Round(ts.TotalDays)` and I was performing integer division on the number of hours with `NSInteger days = hours / 24;`.  This caused 6 days, 23 hours, and 59 minutes to be 6.

Interestingly, future dates are the only place where this rounding applies.  "Yesterday" applies from 24 to 48 hours as you would expect.  I had based my future date code off my past date code, causing the problem.

Comment: What about related bug? I thought it will be fixed too. Or its nature is different?