# Reported ending time for bounty differs on Stack Overflow vs. Android app

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, android-app, bounties

While working on a question with an open bounty, I noticed that the bounty ending time reported by the Stack Overflow site and the Stack Exchange Android App (version 1.0.93) differed. Here is what was reported the last time I checked:

**Android App**

> This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from [OP] ending in 2 days.

**Stack Overflow website**

> This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from [OP] ending tomorrow.

I noticed this difference several times while the bounty was open but a different number of days was reported depending on how many days were left, but the difference was always one day.

The bounty has ended but the question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156642). I am in the Eastern Time Zone. I last checked about 7:34 pm EDT.

Does anyone have an insight into why the bounty ending time in the app would differ from the website?

Comment: Possibly related post for iOS-app: [Stolen bounty day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289453/339911)

Comment: @alexolut Definitely looks related. I guess Android didn't want to be outdone. It is unclear if the mentioned fix will carry over to Android.